# Is $I \cap (\bigcup_{j=0}^{\infty} I_j)$ a half open interval?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

A half open interval is a set of form $\emptyset$ or $[a,b[$ where $a < b$

If $I$ is a half open interval and $I_j, j=0,1,...$ is a sequence of half open intervals, is $I \cap (\bigcup_{j=0}^{\infty} I_j)$ necessary a half open interval?

I tried some examples and it works but don't know how to prove/disprove

I also want to know what happens if there is only a finite number of $I_j$. i.e just $I_1,...,I_n$

thanks

Comment: Um... no.  Let I = [0,100), I2 = [1,2), I3 = [4,5) then $I \cap (I_2 \cup I_3)=[0,1) \cup [2,4)\cup [5,100)$.  Let $I_n = [1/n,1 -1/n)$ the $\cup I_n = (0,1)$ and $[-1,1/2)\cap(\cup I_n) = (0,1/2)$ etc.

Comment: For finite then the result is the union of half closed intervals.  For infinite it can be a union of half closed and open intervals and singletons but I don't think there are any components that are closed on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $I=[0,1)$ and $I_n=\left[\frac1n,1\right)$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: @madmatician: It's still false: you might have $I=[0,3),I_1=[0,1)$, and $I_2=[2,3)$, for instance.